# How do i do authentication with an external api in nuxtjs

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

For the past few hours i've been trying to get cookie based auth working with my go backend and my nuxtjs frontend however nothing seems to work. I tried to implement it from scratch which was a complete disaster, i've tried the "official" nuxt auth package which is outdated as came to find out and i've also tried authJS which has about no documentation for my use case (authenticating with an external backend) from what i've seen. If anyone can direct me to some resource i would be very greatful.

Comment: Which version of nuxt are you using? and which store management(vuex, pinia or anyother) are you using at your nuxt project?

Comment: if you wait just a 2 weeks i will release my nuxt auth according what you want. be patient